# React Native+Firebase/NodeMailer - Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I deployed my Firebase code that sends a test email using [this guide](https://edigleyssonsilva.medium.com/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e), and (finally) successfully invoked the code from within my React Native app by trying to follow the example snippet in [the React Native Firebase docs](https://rnfirebase.io/functions/usage#calling-an-endpoint).

However, when I run the function, React Native gives back a `Possible Unhanlded Promise Rejection` error with the following logs (which shows the detailed Component stack), and I don't receive the test email:

```
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: NOT FOUND
Error: NOT FOUND
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:161257:60
invokePassiveEffectCreate@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:19749:32
invokeGuardedCallbackProd@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:6272:21
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:6376:42
flushPassiveEffectsImpl@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:19819:36
unstable_runWithPriority@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:54580:30
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:19604:36
workLoop@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:54531:48
flushWork@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:54506:28
_flushCallback@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:54216:24
_callTimer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.coreApp2:28655:17
```

[image]

And here are the function logs provided in the Firebase console:

```
3:56:49.762 PM
sendMail
 got here 

3:56:55.222 PM
sendMail
 {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"MyEmail@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/hb-warranty/locations/us-central1/functions/sendMail"}
```

*In my actual logs, `{"principalEmail":"MyEmail@gmail.com"}` shows the actually valid Gmail address from my code.*

I feel like I'm missing some error handling in my code, and I'm not sure how to debug my code using the current logs.

### What changes should be made to my code to improve error handling, and successfully send an email via my Firebase Cloud Function?

---

**Backend Cloud function (`/MyApp/functions/index.js`):**

```js
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const admin = require('firebase-admin')
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
    const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
    admin.initializeApp();
    
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'MyEmail@gmail.com',
            pass: 'MyPass'
        }
    });

    console.log('got here');
    // exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    // cors(req, res, () => {
    
    exports.sendMail = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
        cors(data, () => {
            const dest = data.dest;
    
            const mailOptions = {
                from: 'Test Email <MyEmail@gmail.com>',
                to: dest,
                subject: 'I am squash',
                html: `<p style="font-size: 16px;">Squash Richard</p>
                    <br />
                    <img src="https://i.etsystatic.com/6129578/r/il/858dbc/703555889/il_570xN.703555889_14z1.jpg" />`
            };
      
            return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
                if(erro){
                    return erro.toString();
                }
                return 'Sent';
            });
        });    
    });
```

*Code from [this tutorial](https://edigleyssonsilva.medium.com/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e). In my actual code, `user: MyEmail@gmail.com` and `from: 'Test Email <MyEmail@gmail.com>'` actually use a valid Gmail account, and the account authorizes less secure apps.*

---

**Frontend React Native (`/MyApp/Email.js`):**

```js
    import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';
    
    function EmailScreen() {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        functions().httpsCallable('sendMail')({dest: 'MyOtherEmail@gmail.com'})
    })
    
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>This is the email screen.</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    export default EmailScreen;
```

*Code from [the docs linked above](https://rnfirebase.io/functions/usage#calling-an-endpoint)*

Answer (score 0):

Gmail uses two factor authentication when Gmail servers doesn't recognize the usual ip address from which the account is accessed from. When deploying to the firebase server this can occur as an issue trying to access your account from a unrecognized ip address. The code will still work running in your local machine. To send transactional emails you have to use sendgrid or zoho mails and there are several other options also

Comment: Thanks but it worked after I removed the `cors(data, () => { ... }` line and re-configured the Firebase SDK with my app: https://rnfirebase.io/#3-ios-setup . To my understanding, since I'm using NodeMailer, I don't need a service like SendGrid or Zoho.

Comment: Have you deployed it to the cloud and the mails are being sent?

Comment: Yes, thanks (need these extra characters to add comment)